# Python -- how do I successfully copy data from one object and change one variable without changing the other?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to do something like this:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.initfunc()

    def initfunc(self):
        self.a = 'test'

a = test()
b = test()
a = b

a.a = 'test3'
b.a = 'test4'

print(a.a, b.a)
```

The output is:

```
test4 test4
```

How do I make it so that the output is:

```
test3 test4
```

Also, pickle is not an option. This is a simplified version of a problem I am having with PyQt, and many of the objects in PyQt are not pickle-able.

Comment: No. The output is not what you claim it is. You need to show real code that actually demonstrates the problem. (And this has nothing to do with pickle.)

Comment: Except the output is what I claim it is -- please run it in Python 3.

Comment: Yeah, deepcopy is only for standard library. If an object isn't pickle-able, it can't be deepcopy'd.

Comment: @AndrewVII, please link to an online Python interpreter that demonstrates this not working as expected.

Comment: What is the point of doing ` a = b` here? Why are you doing that, after you create both a and b? If you didn't do this, you would have the output you want. But with it, I can't understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve, but after

```
a = b
```

both names point to the same object. You can verify this like so:

```
a = test()
b = test()

print(id(a), id(b))
a = b    
print(id(a), id(b))
```

In other languages you maybe call this "assign by reference". After you assign `test4` to `b.a`, `a.a` is of course the same value, since they are the same property of the same object.

NB: the original `a` is no longer accessible after the assignment.

You might get what you need with `copy.copy()`:

```
b = test()

print(id(a), id(b))
a = copy(b)

print(id(a), id(b))

a.a = 'test3'
b.a = 'test4'

print(a.a, b.a)
```

but given your comment about `pickle`, you will probaly have to implement the `__copy__()` or `__deepcopy__()` methods.